# Difference between EACCES and EPERM

Tags: c, unix, language-agnostic, posix, errno

What is the difference between EACCES and EPERM exactly? EPERM is described [here](https://github.com/davidar/lljvm/blob/master/java/src/lljvm/runtime/Error.java) as "not super user", but I would usually associate that with EACCES. In fact, I can't recall ever seeing an EPERM in real life.

Comment: just want to add the [GNU source for the error codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) as I got here by looking for what EPERM stands for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`EACCES` is almost always used when the system call was passed a path that was inaccessible by the current user.

`EPERM` is used in various other situations where you need to be root to perform an action, e.g.

- `kill()` on a process that you don't own
- `link()` on a directory
- `reboot()`

Comment: Well, link() on a directory isn't normally allowed to root either, but this answer seems good otherwise.

Comment: @BruceFields Depends on the OS. Some have allowed root to hardlink directories. (Not even just historically; macOS actively uses this feature for backups.)

Comment: Good point!  Maybe I should have said: "link() on a directory returns EPERM even on OS's where hardlinks aren't allowed even to root".

Comment: Note that significant portions of the `sockets(7)` subsystem also tend to return `EACCES` when `EPERM` might make more sense (e.g. creating a raw socket, binding a low network port, etc.).  I imagine it's a Berkeley-ism.

Comment: what is the expansion of EPREM ?

Comment: @divine EPREM is not guaranteed to exist by POSIX. EPERM expands to a positive `int` value by POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) figure into [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) so that if the exec'ing process lacks the correct inheritance/bounding-set/ambient to set the file-capabilities:

"If the process did not obtain the full set of file permitted capabilities, then execve(2) fails with the error EPERM."

Comment: Can you add a source for the quote you provided? Thanks!

Comment: The quote is from [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Comment: is it apply to all *nix OS?