# FreeBSD's namei() call's LOOKUP operation and its errors

Tags: c, linux, freebsd

I looked up man page and everything I could find on the net, but I couldn't find **details** regarding the errors that are thrown for the LOOKUP op of namei() call (FreeeBSD). I even looked at the source code (kern/vfs_lookup.c). My question is, supposing as a typical user (non-root) I want to do a lookup operation on a file (say, 5 which is in /1/2/3/4/5), will the namei() throw EACCES or EPERM if the user doesn't have permissions (search or read or both) on atleast one of the components (say, 3) of the whole file path? namei() should error out EACCES right if there is no search or read perm on dir 3?

Comment: `namei()` is internal to the kernel, I don't think it can be called directly by a user application.

Comment: You should probably show the code that is failing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between EACCES and EPERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023667/difference-between-eacces-and-eperm)

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: if something was denied by permissions (as in, stuff you can set using chmod(1), or ACLs), you get EACCES.  Otherwise, when you try something that does not depend on permissions, for example change file owner, you get EPERM.