# What causes an EPERM error when traversing my home directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, recursion, runtime-error

I googled

> EPERM: operation not permitted

and I got many hits on issues with npm and this error.

This is not my case ( not a duplicate ) as I am not running npm, I am running my own Node code.

I am getting this error:

**Error**

```
{ 
  Error: 'EPERM: operation not permitted',
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '../../../Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB/' 
};
```

when running the code below on my home directory.

I ran it using both

> node getInfo

and

> sudo node getInfo

but I get the same error.

This code works fine if I run it on my local repository but when I try to traverse my entire home directory I get the error.

**Executed code:**

```
// Libraries
const fs = require('fs');
const h = require('./helper');

// Start recursing here
const start = '../../../';

// API
getThings(start).then(() => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(h.error)

// Accesses the file system and returns an array of files / folders
async function getThings (folder) { 
  const things = await fs.promises.readdir(folder);
  for(let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    await getStats(things[i], folder);
  }
}

// Gets statistics for each file/folder
async function getStats (thing, folder) {
  const path = folder + thing;
  const stats = await fs.promises.stat(path);
  await checkForFolder(stats, thing, path); 
}

// if the file/folder is a folder, recurse and do it again
async function checkForFolder(stats, thing, path){
  // logThing(stats, thing, path);
  if (stats.isDirectory() ) {
    await getThings(path + '/');
  }
}
```

**Research**

[SO - EPERM vs EACCES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023667/difference-between-eacces-and-eperm)

Comment: Have you tryed to rebuilding it is a generic error. The real error is not this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'../../../Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB/'
```

This path is protected by macOS security settings, as it may contain sensitive telephone history data.

If you specifically need to access it in your Node application, you will need to enable full disk access for the application you're using to run this script (e.g, Terminal.app, iTerm, or an IDE) in System Preferences, as shown below. Note that this will give *all* applications you run in the terminal access to your sensitive personal files; tread carefully.

However, if you don't need to specifically access this path (and you probably shouldn't), a better solution may be to catch errors individually on each call to `fs.promises.stat(path)`. The simplest way of doing this will be to wrap the call to `await fs.promises.stat(path)` in a `try … catch` block and either print or ignore errors.

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me work towards a fix for a 'scandir' I was getting. In my case I also had to make sure that "Network Volumes" access was enabled for my "iTerm.app" in the  "File & Folders" section which is also found in the "Privacy" tab pictured in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to the question. But an example where I got this error. I got this error suddenly when ran `vite serve` command in command prompt of my Windows machine. This command was working fine until I made a change in `vite.config.js`, where I changed the value contained in `root` key to `/` instead of it's earlier value of `./`. I don't know the exact reason but here is what I think could be happening basis the clues from the accepted answer. I am working on company's laptop and my project folder resides in the root of `C:` drive. When the `root` key value in `vite.config.js` is `/`, Vite is trying to navigate to `Perf` directory in `C:`drive. I don't know why. I am a normal user(non admin) and doesn't have permission navigate to this directory and so is Vite so I am getting similar error. My error looked like below -

```
> vite serve

node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\PerfLogs'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\PerfLogs'
}
```

My `errorno` in above error is different as per my case but notice the path `C:\\PerfLogs`. When I traverse to this path and click on this folder I get below -

[image]

I hope it helps someone who is facing similar kind of permission issue.